# No stream value when requesting a Deezer track through vanilla HTTP

Tags: android, api, deezer

For example issuing an HTTP GET on:
https://api.deezer.com/track/3980888?access_token=xxx
Where access_token is a valid Premium+ token. The response does not include a stream field. It is however included if (for example) using DeezerConnect and DeezerRequest from the Deezer Android SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a valid stream in the API response, you need to provide the `access_token` as you do, as well as an `imei` parameter.

This `imei` parameter is then used to decode the stream and play the track. Unfortunately, not all Android device have an IMEI number, so the Deezer SDK uses it's own way to generate this value.

That's why you really should use the DeezerConnect / DeezerRequest system to call the API, to be sure that you get a correct Stream.

Comment: Thanks Xavier! Any chance `Util.getImei` can be made public in a future SDK release? I'm currently using reflection to read out the internal imei field from your `DeezerConnect` instance, but this is obviously a very fragile hack.  PS: The reason I'm using vanilla HTTP is because the app is already using https://github.com/koush/ion for REST, image loading, WebSocket, etc., as it integrates nicely with the Android UI thread while performing non-blocking I/O with NIO from a background thread (with HTTP pipelining support and other goodies).

Comment: We'll see if we do, but for now your hack will probably work fine